# Multiple priors in Bayesian estimation

Tags: bayesian, estimation, prior

Typical Bayesian estimation equation is:

Estimate = ( SampleSize * SampleEstimate + PrioriEstimateWeight * PrioriEstimate) / ( SampleSize + PrioriEstimateWeight )

Typically, the PrioriEstimate is the overall average for the entire population.

I've seen 2 or 3 recommended for a PrioriEstimateWeight.

This is usually done with restaurant reviews. Let's say Cafe A has 3 reviews with an average rating of 100%.
Cafe B has 100 ratings and a rating of 95%, most people will trust that Cafe B is a better restaurant.

Let's say the average rating is 50% for all restaurants (the national mean), then a Bayesian estimation of Cafe A is:

(3 * 1.00 + 2 * 0.50)/(3+2)=0.80 or 80%

For Cafe B:
(100 * 0.95 + 2 * 0.50)/(100+2)=94.1%

But now let's say, you wish to use 2 priori. The county mean and the national mean. Let's say the national mean sample size is 1 million.

Let's say Cafe A is in a rural county and Cafe B is in a big city.

The rural county has 50 overall reviews with a mean of 97%. That particular county may be a secret foodies' delight.

And Cafe B is in the big city county with 10,000 reviews with an average review of 53%

What is a good formula for combining multiple priori together?

Cafe A:

(3 * 1.00 + ? * 0.97 + 2 * 0.50)/(3+?+2)=??

What should the ? weight be given that it's a sample of 50 for the county? Also, why have 2 be the weight for the national priori? Should it be based on the sample size of 1 million?